# Enhancement of bloques tikz library

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzlibrary

**I'll let this question open for a few more days if someone posts an interesting answer**

I came across bloques library for tikz (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/bloques), found it quite nice but I soon noticed it was lacking some options, so I decided to rework it / extend features.

I achieved this style file so far:

```
\usepackage{tikz,circuitikz}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,shadows}

\newcommand{\horizdist}{1.5cm}
\newcommand{\verticdist}{1.2cm}
\newcommand{\phasedist}{3.5cm}
\newcommand{\minheight}{0.7cm}
\newcommand{\textsize}{\footnotesize}
\newcommand{\backgroundcolor}{white}
\newcommand{\colortext}{black}
\newcommand{\linecolor}{black}
\newcommand{\dark}{0}
\newcommand{\linetype}{thick}

\newcommand{\bShadow}{\renewcommand{\dark}{1}}
\newcommand{\bColorB}[1]{\renewcommand{\backgroundcolor}{#1}}
\newcommand{\bColorT}[1]{\renewcommand{\colortext}{#1}}
\newcommand{\bColorL}[1]{\renewcommand{\linecolor}{#1}}

\newcommand{\bDownTo}[3]{
    \node[above of=#1, node distance=\verticdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor] (#2) {\textsize{#3}};
    \draw[-latex, \linetype] (#2) -- (#1);
}

\newcommand{\bUpTo}[3]{
    \node[below of=#1, node distance=\verticdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor] (#2) {\textsize{#3}};
    \draw[-latex, \linetype] (#2) -- (#1);
}

\newcommand{\bRightTo}[3]{
    \node[left of=#1, node distance=\horizdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor] (#2) {\textsize{#3}};
    \draw[-latex, \linetype] (#2) -- (#1);
}

\newcommand{\bLeftTo}[3]{
    \node[left of=#1, node distance=\horizdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor] (#2) {\textsize{#3}};
    \draw[-latex, \linetype] (#2) -- (#1);
}

\newcommand{\bPlusDown}[2]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of=#1, node distance= \horizdist,\linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {};
    \node [draw=gray!50, cross out, minimum size=1.0em, right of=#1, node distance= \horizdist, thin] {};   
    \node [left of = #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \node [below of = #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \draw [-latex,\linetype] (#1) -- (#2);          
}

\newcommand{\bPlusUp}[2]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of=#1, node distance= \horizdist,\linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {};
    \node [draw=gray!50, cross out, minimum size=1.0em, right of=#1, node distance= \horizdist, thin, draw=gray!50] {}; 
    \node [left of = #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \node [above of = #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1) -- (#2);                
}

\newcommand{\bMinusDown}[2]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of=#1, node distance= \horizdist,\linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {};
    \node [draw=gray!50, cross out, minimum size=1.0em, right of=#1, node distance= \horizdist, thin] {};   
    \node [left of = #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \node [below of = #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$-$}};
    \draw [-latex,\linetype] (#1) -- (#2);          
}

\newcommand{\bMinusUp}[2]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of=#1, node distance= \horizdist,\linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {};
    \node [draw=gray!50, cross out, minimum size=1.0em, right of=#1, node distance= \horizdist, thin, draw=gray!50] {}; 
    \node [left of = #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \node [above of = #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$-$}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1) -- (#2);        
}

\newcommand{\bMinusPlus}[2]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of=#1, node distance= \horizdist,\linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {};
    \node [draw, cross out, minimum size=1.0em, right of=#1, node distance= \horizdist, thin, draw=gray!50] {}; 
    \node [left of = #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \node [above of = #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$-$}};
    \node [below of = #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1) -- (#2);            
}

\newcommand{\bPlusMinus}[2]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of=#1, node distance= \horizdist,\linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {};
    \node [draw, cross out, minimum size=1.0em, right of=#1, node distance= \horizdist, thin, draw=gray!50] {}; 
    \node [left of = #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \node [above of = #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \node [below of = #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$-$}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1) -- (#2);            
}

\newcommand{\bMinusMinus}[2]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of=#1, node distance= \horizdist,\linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {};
    \node [draw, cross out, minimum size=1.0em, right of=#1, node distance= \horizdist, thin, draw=gray!50] {}; 
    \node [left of = #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \node [above of = #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$-$}};
    \node [below of = #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$-$}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1) -- (#2);            
}

\newcommand{\bPlusPlus}[2]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of=#1, node distance= \horizdist,\linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {};
    \node [draw, cross out, minimum size=1.0em, right of=#1, node distance= \horizdist, thin, draw=gray!50] {}; 
    \node [left of = #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \node [above of = #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \node [below of = #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1) -- (#2);            
}

\newcommand{\bGain}[3]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle, right of = #1, node distance= \horizdist, minimum size = 1.5em, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) { \color{\colortext}\textsize{#3}}; 
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1)--(#2);
}

\newcommand{\bGainBackDown}[4]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle, below right of = #1, node distance=\horizdist+.1cm, minimum size = 1.5em, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark},anchor=west] (#3) { \color{\colortext}\textsize{#4}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#2)|-(#3);
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#3)-|(#1);
}

\newcommand{\bGainBackUp}[4]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle, above right of = #1, node distance=\horizdist+.1cm, minimum size = 1.5em, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark},anchor=west] (#3) { \color{\colortext}\textsize{#4}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#2)|-(#3);
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#3)-|(#1);
}

\newcommand{\bGainBackUpCross}[4]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle, above left of = #1, node distance=\horizdist+.1cm, minimum size = 1.5em, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark},anchor=east] (#3) { \color{\colortext}\textsize{#4}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1)|-(#3);
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#3) -- ++(-\horizdist/2,0) -- ($(#2)-(0,\verticdist)$) -- (#2);
}

\newcommand{\bGainBackDownCross}[4]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle, below left of = #1, node distance=\horizdist+.1cm, minimum size = 1.5em, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark},anchor=east] (#3) { \color{\colortext}\textsize{#4}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1)|-(#3);
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#3) -- ++(-\horizdist/2,0) -- ($(#2)+(0,\verticdist)$) -- (#2);
}

\newcommand{\bTF}[3]{       
    \node [draw=\linecolor, rectangle, right of = #1, node distance= \horizdist, minimum height = \minheight, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {\color{\colortext}\textsize{#3}};    
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1)--(#2);
}

\newcommand{\bTFForthUpCross}[4]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, rectangle, above right of = #1, node distance=\horizdist+.1cm, minimum height = \minheight, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor,drop shadow={opacity=\dark},anchor=west] (#3) { \color{\colortext}\textsize{#4}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1)|-(#3);
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#3) -- ++(\horizdist/2,0) -- ($(#2)-(0,\verticdist)$) -- (#2);
}

\newcommand{\bTFForthDownCross}[4]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, rectangle, below right of = #1, node distance=\horizdist+.1cm, minimum height = \minheight, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor,drop shadow={opacity=\dark},anchor=west] (#3) { \color{\colortext}\textsize{#4}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1)|-(#3);
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#3) -- ++(\horizdist/2,0) -- ($(#2)+(0,\verticdist)$) -- (#2);
}

\newcommand{\bMarkNode}[2]{
    \node[fill=\linecolor,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=.5em,right of = #1, node distance= \horizdist] (#2) {};
    \draw [\linecolor] (#1)--(#2);
}

\newcommand{\bOut}[3]{
    \node[right of=#1, node distance= \horizdist] (#2) {\color{\colortext}\textsize{#3}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1)--(#2);
}
```

I was able with this example to draw the block diagram of a RL load and it's corresponding control in synchronous reference frame (for those who know about that, but it's just for the example purpose).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bloquesshapes} % above sty file

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \bShadow
    \node (1) at (0,0) {\color{\colortext}\textsize{$i_{sc\alpha}$}};
    \bMinusUp{1}{2}
    \bDownTo{2}{3}{$i_{s\alpha}$}
    \bMinusPlus{2}{3}
    \bTF{3}{4}{$\dfrac{1}{sl}$}
    \bMarkNode{4}{5}
    \bGainBackUp{3}{5}{6}{$r$}
    \bOut{5}{7}{$i_{s\alpha}$}
    \node (A) at (0,-\phasedist) {\color{\colortext}\textsize{$u_{s\beta}$}};
    \bMinusDown{A}{B}
    \bUpTo{B}{C}{$u_{i\beta}$}
    \bMinusMinus{B}{C}
    \bTF{C}{D}{$\dfrac{1}{sl}$}
    \bMarkNode{D}{E}
    \bGainBackDown{C}{E}{F}{$r$}
    \bOut{E}{G}{$i_{s\beta}$}
    \bGainBackUpCross{E}{3}{H}{$\omega l$}
    \bGainBackDownCross{5}{C}{8}{$\omega l$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth']
    \bShadow
    \node (1) at (0,0) {\color{\colortext}\textsize{$i_{sc\alpha}$}};
    \bMinusUp{1}{2}
    \bDownTo{2}{3}{$i_{s\alpha}$}
    \bMarkNode{2}{3}
    \bTF{3}{4}{$\frac{1+sT_n}{sT_i}$}
    \bMinusDown{4}{5}
    \bOut{5}{7}{$u_{cm\alpha}$}
    \node (A) at (0,-\phasedist) {\color{\colortext}\textsize{$i_{sc\beta}$}};
    \bMinusDown{A}{B}
    \bUpTo{B}{C}{$i_{s\beta}$}
    \bMarkNode{B}{C}
    \bTF{C}{D}{$\frac{1+sT_n}{sT_i}$}
    \bPlusUp{D}{E}
    \bOut{E}{G}{$u_{cm\beta}$}
    \bTFForthDownCross{3}{E}{H}{$\dfrac{\omega T_n}{sT_i}$}
    \bTFForthUpCross{C}{5}{8}{$\dfrac{\omega T_n}{sT_i}$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The graphical result is quite nice in my opinion.
[image: illustration]

I would appreciate:

- any idea on how to actually make in a simpler way the same drawing
- a `\bStart`command who take as input a node name, a node position (x,y) and a node label (the trick has to be found for the node position)
- a fix for the `\bMarkNode` (delete white space around the thick dot)
- a less trick way for `$r$` and `$\omega l$` nodes (vertical alignment)
- for more flexibility I had to increase complexity with a variable amount of arguments for the commands, something that was not present with bloques; any idea is welcome **All shapes of the same kind take the same number of arguments**

Comment: I'm guessing there's a typo in your first line. If so, you might want to correct it lest people run away screaming... ;).

Comment: damn auto-correction... thx @cfr

Answer (score 2):

Ok I think I go it this time.

- The drawing commands seems simple enough for me.
- `\bStart` I don't care
- `\bMarkNode` fixed with inner/outer sep
- Vertical alignement fixed. As above right and other behave weird, I decided to do so: `above/below of=, distance=\verticdist, xshift=+-\horizdist`
- More or less done.

Here is my style file at this moment:

```
\usepackage{tikz,circuitikz}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,fit,shadows}

\newcommand{\horizdist}{1.5cm}
\newcommand{\verticdist}{1.2cm}
\newcommand{\phasedist}{3.5cm}
\newcommand{\minheight}{0.7cm}
\newcommand{\textsize}{\footnotesize}
\newcommand{\backgroundcolor}{white}
\newcommand{\colortext}{black}
\newcommand{\linecolor}{black}
\newcommand{\dark}{0}
\newcommand{\linetype}{thick}

\newcommand{\bShadow}{\renewcommand{\dark}{1}}
\newcommand{\bColorB}[1]{\renewcommand{\backgroundcolor}{#1}}
\newcommand{\bColorT}[1]{\renewcommand{\colortext}{#1}}
\newcommand{\bColorL}[1]{\renewcommand{\linecolor}{#1}}

\tikzset{every node/.style={anchor=center, text centered, align=center}}

\newcommand{\bDownTo}[3]{
    \node[above of= #1, node distance=\verticdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor] (#2) {\textsize{#3}};
    \draw[-latex, \linecolor] (#2) -- (#1);
}

\newcommand{\bDownToGain}[5]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle, above of= #1, node distance= \verticdist, minimum size = 1.5em, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {\color{\colortext}\textsize{#3}};
    \node[above of= #2, node distance=\verticdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor] (#4) {\textsize{#5}};
    \draw[-latex, \linecolor] (#2) -- (#1);
    \draw[-latex, \linecolor] (#4) -- (#2);
}

\newcommand{\bUpToGain}[5]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle, below of= #1, node distance= \verticdist, minimum size = 1.5em, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {\color{\colortext}\textsize{#3}};
    \node[below of=#2, node distance=\verticdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor] (#4) {\textsize{#5}};
    \draw[-latex, \linecolor] (#2) -- (#1);
    \draw[-latex, \linecolor] (#4) -- (#2);
}

\newcommand{\bUpTo}[3]{
    \node[below of= #1, node distance=\verticdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor] (#2) {\textsize{#3}};
    \draw[-latex, \linecolor] (#2) -- (#1);
}

\newcommand{\bRightTo}[3]{
    \node[left of= #1, node distance=\horizdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor] (#2) {\textsize{#3}};
    \draw[-latex, \linecolor] (#2) -- (#1);
}

\newcommand{\bLeftTo}[3]{
    \node[left of= #1, node distance=\horizdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor] (#2) {\textsize{#3}};
    \draw[-latex, \linecolor] (#2) -- (#1);
}

\newcommand{\bPlusDown}[2]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {};
    \node [draw=gray!50, cross out, minimum size=1.0em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, thin] {};  
    \node [left of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \node [below of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \draw [-latex,\linecolor] (#1) -- (#2);         
}

\newcommand{\bPlusUp}[2]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {};
    \node [draw=gray!50, cross out, minimum size=1.0em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, thin, draw=gray!50] {};    
    \node [left of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \node [above of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1) -- (#2);                
}

\newcommand{\bMinusDown}[2]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {};
    \node [draw=gray!50, cross out, minimum size=1.0em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, thin] {};  
    \node [left of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \node [below of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$-$}};
    \draw [-latex,\linecolor] (#1) -- (#2);         
}

\newcommand{\bMinusUp}[2]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {};
    \node [draw=gray!50, cross out, minimum size=1.0em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, thin, draw=gray!50] {};    
    \node [left of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \node [above of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$-$}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1) -- (#2);        
}

\newcommand{\bMinusPlus}[2]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {};
    \node [draw, cross out, minimum size=1.0em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, thin, draw=gray!50] {};    
    \node [left of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \node [above of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$-$}};
    \node [below of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1) -- (#2);            
}

\newcommand{\bMinusPlusDown}[2]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {};
    \node [draw, cross out, minimum size=1.0em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, thin, draw=gray!50] {};    
    \node [left of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$-$}};
    \node [below of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1) -- (#2);            
}

\newcommand{\bMinusMinusDown}[2]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {};
    \node [draw, cross out, minimum size=1.0em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, thin, draw=gray!50] {};    
    \node [left of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$-$}};
    \node [below of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$-$}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1) -- (#2);            
}

\newcommand{\bPlusMinusDown}[2]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {};
    \node [draw, cross out, minimum size=1.0em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, thin, draw=gray!50] {};    
    \node [left of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \node [below of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$-$}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1) -- (#2);            
}

\newcommand{\bPlusPlusDown}[2]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {};
    \node [draw, cross out, minimum size=1.0em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, thin, draw=gray!50] {};    
    \node [left of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \node [below of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1) -- (#2);            
}

\newcommand{\bMinusPlusUp}[2]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {};
    \node [draw, cross out, minimum size=1.0em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, thin, draw=gray!50] {};    
    \node [left of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$-$}};
    \node [above of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1) -- (#2);            
}

\newcommand{\bMinusMinusUp}[2]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {};
    \node [draw, cross out, minimum size=1.0em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, thin, draw=gray!50] {};    
    \node [left of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$-$}};
    \node [above of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$-$}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1) -- (#2);            
}

\newcommand{\bPlusMinusUp}[2]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {};
    \node [draw, cross out, minimum size=1.0em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, thin, draw=gray!50] {};    
    \node [left of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \node [above of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$-$}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1) -- (#2);            
}

\newcommand{\bPlusPlusUp}[2]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {};
    \node [draw, cross out, minimum size=1.0em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, thin, draw=gray!50] {};    
    \node [left of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \node [above of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1) -- (#2);            
}

\newcommand{\bPlusMinus}[2]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {};
    \node [draw, cross out, minimum size=1.0em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, thin, draw=gray!50] {};    
    \node [left of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \node [above of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \node [below of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$-$}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1) -- (#2);            
}

\newcommand{\bMinusMinus}[2]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {};
    \node [draw, cross out, minimum size=1.0em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, thin, draw=gray!50] {};    
    \node [left of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \node [above of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$-$}};
    \node [below of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$-$}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1) -- (#2);            
}

\newcommand{\bPlusPlus}[2]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle,minimum size=1.5em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {};
    \node [draw, cross out, minimum size=1.0em, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, thin, draw=gray!50] {};    
    \node [left of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \node [above of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \node [below of= #2, node distance = 0.45em] () { \color{\colortext}\tiny{$+$}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1) -- (#2);            
}

\newcommand{\bGain}[3]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, minimum size = 1.5em, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {\color{\colortext}\textsize{#3}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1)--(#2);
}

\newcommand{\bGainForthDown}[3]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle, below of= #1, node distance=\verticdist, xshift=\horizdist, minimum size = 1.5em, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {\color{\colortext}\textsize{#3}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1)|-(#2);
}

\newcommand{\bGainForthUp}[3]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle, above of= #1, node distance=\verticdist, xshift=\horizdist, minimum size = 1.5em, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {\color{\colortext}\textsize{#3}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1)|-(#2);
}

\newcommand{\bGainBackDown}[4]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle, below of= #1, node distance=\verticdist, xshift=\horizdist, minimum size = 1.5em, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#3) {\color{\colortext}\textsize{#4}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#2)|-(#3);
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#3)-|(#1);
}

\newcommand{\bGainBackUp}[4]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle, above of= #1, node distance= \verticdist, xshift=\horizdist, minimum size = 1.5em, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#3) {\color{\colortext}\textsize{#4}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#2)|-(#3);
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#3)-|(#1);
}

\newcommand{\bGainBackUpCross}[4]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle, above of= #1, node distance= \verticdist, xshift=-\horizdist, minimum size = 1.5em, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#3) { \color{\colortext}\textsize{#4}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1)|-(#3);
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#3) -- ++(-\horizdist/2,0) -- ($(#2)-(0,\verticdist)$) -- (#2);
}

\newcommand{\bGainBackDownCross}[4]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle, below of= #1, node distance= \verticdist, xshift=-\horizdist, minimum size = 1.5em, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#3) { \color{\colortext}\textsize{#4}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1)|-(#3);
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#3) -- ++(-\horizdist/2,0) -- ($(#2)+(0,\verticdist)$) -- (#2);
}

\newcommand{\bGainForthUpCross}[4]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle, above of= #1, node distance= \verticdist, xshift=\horizdist, minimum size = 1.5em, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#3) { \color{\colortext}\textsize{#4}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1)|-(#3);
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#3) -- ++(\horizdist/2,0) -- ($(#2)-(0,\verticdist)$) -- (#2);
}

\newcommand{\bGainForthDownCross}[4]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, circle, below of= #1, node distance= \verticdist, xshift=\horizdist, minimum size = 1.5em, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#3) { \color{\colortext}\textsize{#4}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1)|-(#3);
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#3) -- ++(\horizdist/2,0) -- ($(#2)+(0,\verticdist)$) -- (#2);
}

\newcommand{\bTF}[3]{       
    \node [draw=\linecolor, rectangle, right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist, minimum height = \minheight, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {\color{\colortext}\textsize{#3}}; 
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1)--(#2);
}

\newcommand{\bTFForthDown}[3]{      
    \node [draw=\linecolor, rectangle, below of= #1, node distance= \verticdist, xshift=\horizdist, minimum height = \minheight, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {\color{\colortext}\textsize{#3}}; 
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1)|-(#2);
}

\newcommand{\bTFForthUp}[3]{        
    \node [draw=\linecolor, rectangle, above of= #1, node distance= \verticdist, xshift=\horizdist, minimum height = \minheight, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor, drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#2) {\color{\colortext}\textsize{#3}}; 
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1)|-(#2);
}

\newcommand{\bTFForthUpCross}[4]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, rectangle, above of= #1, node distance= \verticdist, xshift=\horizdist, minimum height = \minheight, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor,drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#3) { \color{\colortext}\textsize{#4}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1)|-(#3);
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#3) -- ++(\horizdist/2,0) -- ($(#2)-(0,\verticdist)$) -- (#2);
}

\newcommand{\bTFForthDownCross}[4]{
    \node [draw=\linecolor, rectangle, below of= #1, node distance= \verticdist, xshift=\horizdist, minimum height = \minheight, \linetype, fill=\backgroundcolor,drop shadow={opacity=\dark}] (#3) { \color{\colortext}\textsize{#4}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1)|-(#3);
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#3) -- ++(\horizdist/2,0) -- ($(#2)+(0,\verticdist)$) -- (#2);
}

\newcommand{\bMarkNode}[2]{
    \node[fill=\linecolor,circle,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, minimum size=.5em,right of = #1, node distance= \horizdist] (#2) {};
    \draw [\linecolor] (#1)--(#2);
}

\newcommand{\bJumpNode}[3]{
    \coordinate (#2) at (#3);
    \draw [\linecolor] (#1)--(#2);
}

\newcommand{\bLink}[2]{
    \draw [-latex,\linecolor] (#1)--(#2);
}

\newcommand{\bOut}[3]{
    \node[right of= #1, node distance= \horizdist] (#2) {\color{\colortext}\textsize{#3}};
    \draw [-latex, \linecolor] (#1)--(#2);
}
```

And 3 examples to show what can be (simply) done.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bloquesshapes} % the above .sty file

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \bShadow
    \node (1) at (0,0) {\color{\colortext}\textsize{$i_{sc\alpha}$}};
    \bMinusUp{1}{2}
    \bDownTo{2}{3}{$i_{s\alpha}$}
    \bMinusPlus{2}{3}
    \bTF{3}{4}{$\dfrac{1}{sl}$}
    \bMarkNode{4}{5}
    \bGainBackUp{3}{5}{6}{$r$}
    \bOut{5}{7}{$i_{s\alpha}$}
    \node (A) at (0,-\phasedist) {\color{\colortext}\textsize{$u_{s\beta}$}};
    \bMinusDown{A}{B}
    \bUpTo{B}{C}{$u_{i\beta}$}
    \bMinusMinus{B}{C}
    \bTF{C}{D}{$\dfrac{1}{sl}$}
    \bMarkNode{D}{E}
    \bGainBackDown{C}{E}{F}{$r$}
    \bOut{E}{G}{$i_{s\beta}$}
    \bGainBackUpCross{E}{3}{H}{$\omega l$}
    \bGainBackDownCross{5}{C}{8}{$\omega l$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \bShadow
    \node (1) at (0,0) {\color{\colortext}\textsize{$i_{sc\alpha}$}};
    \bMinusUp{1}{2}
    \bDownTo{2}{3}{$i_{s\alpha}$}
    \bMarkNode{2}{3}
    \bTF{3}{4}{$\frac{1+sT_n}{sT_i}$}
    \bMinusDown{4}{5}
    \bOut{5}{7}{$u_{cm\alpha}$}
    \node (A) at (0,-\phasedist) {\color{\colortext}\textsize{$i_{sc\beta}$}};
    \bMinusDown{A}{B}
    \bUpTo{B}{C}{$i_{s\beta}$}
    \bMarkNode{B}{C}
    \bTF{C}{D}{$\frac{1+sT_n}{sT_i}$}
    \bPlusUp{D}{E}
    \bOut{E}{G}{$u_{cm\beta}$}
    \bTFForthDownCross{3}{E}{H}{$\dfrac{\omega T_n}{sT_i}$}
    \bTFForthUpCross{C}{5}{8}{$\dfrac{\omega T_n}{sT_i}$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \bShadow
    \node (1) at ($(0,0)+(0,\verticdist)$) {\color{\colortext}\textsize{$i_{c\alpha}$}};
    \bMinusUp{1}{2}
    \bDownTo{2}{3}{$i_{\alpha}$}
    \bMarkNode{2}{4}
    \bTFForthDown{4}{5}{$\dfrac{1}{sT_e}$}
    \bMarkNode{5}{6}
    \bGain{6}{7}{$k_{Rr}$}
    \bPlusMinusDown{7}{8}
    \coordinate[right of=4, node distance=2*\horizdist] (10);
    \bJumpNode{4}{10}{10}
    \bGain{10}{11}{$k_w$}
    \bMinusPlus{11}{12}
    \bLink{8}{12}
    \bDownToGain{12}{13}{$k_v$}{14}{$u_{i\alpha}$}
    \bOut{12}{15}{$y_{R\alpha}$}
    \node (A) at ($(0,0)+(0,-\phasedist-\verticdist)$) {\color{\colortext}\textsize{$i_{c\beta}$}};
    \bMinusDown{A}{B}
    \bUpTo{B}{C}{$i_{\beta}$}
    \bMarkNode{B}{D}
    \bTFForthUp{D}{E}{$\dfrac{1}{sT_e}$}
    \bMarkNode{E}{F}
    \bGain{F}{G}{$k_{Rr}$}
    \bPlusPlusUp{G}{H}
    \coordinate[right of=D, node distance=2*\horizdist] (J);
    \bJumpNode{D}{J}{J}
    \bGain{J}{K}{$k_w$}
    \bPlusMinus{K}{L}
    \bLink{H}{L}
    \bUpToGain{L}{M}{$k_v$}{N}{$u_{i\beta}$}
    \bOut{L}{O}{$y_{R\alpha}$}
    \bGainForthDownCross{6}{H}{9}{$k_{Ri}$}
    \bGainForthUpCross{F}{8}{I}{$k_{Ri}$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The visual result is the following
[image: 3 examples]